# How can I reduce repetition in a filter that uses the && and || operators?

Tags: javascript, filter, logical-operators

I've created a filter that checks for events happening today at certain venues using an events API.  The filter works, but it seems ripe for refactoring given the repetition of `event.venue.name`

This is my code:

```
const tomorrow = moment()
        .add(1, "days")
        .format("LL");

      const optimalVenuesWithEventsTomorrow = eventsData.events.filter(
        event =>
          moment(event.datetime_local).format("LL") === tomorrow &&
          (event.venue.name === "Fenway Park" ||
            event.venue.name === "TD Garden" ||
            event.venue.name === "Charles Playhouse" ||
            event.venue.name === "Citizens Bank Opera House" ||
            event.venue.name === "House of Blues - Boston" ||
            event.venue.name === "Orpheum Theatre" ||
            event.venue.name === "Shubert Theatre")
      );
```

This seems like a simple problem of moving the parentheses around to adjust the logic.  I've tried that, but end up breaking the logic.  What am I missing?

Thanks!

Comment: In similar cases I do two things: 1. `const venueNames = ["fenway park", "td garden", ...];` 2. `venueNames.includes(event.venue.name);` in the filter callback. I think this pattern will keep the values (venue names in this example) easy to refactor, and it can be deemed as configuration

Comment: Thanks @AlexSzabó.  I'd say your response worked better for me than the one noted by the folks that closed the question out as a duplicate.